# Resize UIWebView in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I'm getting the new size of a UIWebView threw its delegate =

```
#pragma mark - UIWebView delegate 
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"Taille resizée = %f", [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero].height);
    CGRect frameTitle = CGRectMake(10, 0, [webView frame].size.width, [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero].height);
    webView.frame = frameTitle;
}
```

but it's too late for the datasource of the UITableView, which construct the table before the previous fonction is called. What is the best way to deal with this problem ?

For the moment, the best solution I have found is :

```
#pragma mark - UIWebView delegate 
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"Taille resizée = %f", [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero].height);
    CGRect frameTitle = CGRectMake(10, 0, [webView frame].size.width, [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero].height);
    webView.frame = frameTitle;
    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

But I don't find this elegant, because the table load twice its data.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i reload my tableview based on the height of UIWebView. It worked well for me.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview{
float webHeight;
CGRect frame = webview.frame;
frame.size.height = 1;
webview.frame = frame;
CGSize fittingSize = [webview sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
frame.size = fittingSize;
webview.frame = frame;
webHeight=fittingSize.height;
rowHt=webHeight;
[aTableView reloadData];
```

}

Hope this helps

Comment: ah ! I just added an edit. That's what I've done for the moment. But it load twice the data and it's not the best for the CPU.

Comment: Twice the data ? Could u pls explain more on tat ? And also post some more code of urs...

Comment: You need to give the new row height obtained in the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method of the tableview

Comment: yes it's working but it's not efficient enough. As you call reloadData, the data are reloaded. Then you go twice in heightForRowAtIndexPath.